# Find the data between two datasets which is within two weeks R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having two dataframes as follows,

```
data1
         Type         date
    1      A      2011-10-21
    2      A      2011-11-18
    3      A      2011-12-16
    4      B      2011-10-20
    5      B      2011-11-17
    6      B      2011-12-15
```

and

```
data2
                 Date              Type        value
    1        2011-10-25              A           1
    2        2011-10-15              A           3
    3        2011-11-10              A           4
    4        2011-10-23              B           12
    5        2011-10-27              B           1
    6        2011-11-18              B           1
```

I want to loop through the type(A,B) of data1 and check for each date and check all the entries for type(A,B) in data2 and check for the dates in data2 which is within two weeks gap, and then sum the values and bring it as an output.

My ideal output would be

```
      Type         date       Value
1      A      2011-10-21        4 (3+1)
2      A      2011-11-18        4
3      A      2011-12-16        NA ( No values for A within two weeks)
4      B      2011-10-20        13 ( 12+1)
5      B      2011-11-17        1
6      B      2011-12-15        NA ( No values for A within two weeks)
```

I can think of writing a loop in R and running through. But it is running for a long time. I guess there should be a better way in dplyr to do this. I am trying and not able to complete it. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How does this look? Assuming `data1` as `df1` and `data2` as `df2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "Type")
df3 <- df3 %>% mutate(date1 = week(date), Date1 = week(Date))
df4 <- df3 %>% mutate(Key = ifelse(((date1 - Date1) %in% c(-2:2)), T, F)) 
df5 <- df4 %>% filter(Key == T) %>% group_by(Type, date) %>% 
summarise(Value = sum(value))
full_join(df1, df5, by = c("Type", "date"))
```